# next state controller is loaded before redirect to login

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I am have used angular fullstack yeoman generator to generate my site's starting point.
I am facing a problem with redirecting the user to a login page when he accesses a restricted page - what seems to happen is that the controller of the restricted page is loaded before the redirect. 
Its important to say that the problem **only happens after building for distribution via grunt**.

I didn't change much of the original generated code:

```
  Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function (loggedIn) {
    if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
      // store the requested url if not logged in
      if ($location.url() != '/login') {
        $cookies.put('returnUrl', $location.url());
      }
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  }
```